# Refreshing ng-repeat list after adding an element

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of orders that I sort based on status key. Then I display it using ng-repeat in bars. I can click Accept button to move one order from submitted to accepted. The question is: How do I refresh the bar displaying accepted orders?

HTML

```
    <div class="bar" ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="order in submitted">
            <div  >
                <p >{{order.name}} </p>
                <p>{{order.total}}</p>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="acceptOrder(order)">Akceptuj</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>

    <div class="bar" ng-controller="AdminCtrl" >
        <li ng-repeat="order in delivery">
            <div >
                <p >{{order.name}} </p>
                <p>{{order.total}}</p>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="addOrderToDeliveryQueue(order)">Dodaj do kolejki dostawy</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
    $scope.submitted = [];
    $scope.accepted = [];
    $scope.delivery = [];


    angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(value, key) {
        if (value.status == 'submitted')
            $scope.submitted.push(value);
        if (value.status == 'accepted')
            $scope.accepted.push(value);
        if (value.status == 'delivery')
            $scope.delivery.push(value);
    });

    $scope.acceptOrder = function(order) {
        var index = $scope.submitted.indexOf(order);
        order.status = 'accepted';
        $scope.accepted.push(order);
        $scope.submitted.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS handles refreshing `ng-repeat` directives automatically when it sees a change in the collection. You are not seeing this behavior because you are actually creating multiple independent instances of your `AdminCtrl` controller. Each of your `div`s has this: `ng-controller="AdminCtrl"`. This creates a new instance of the `AdminCtrl` scoped to that `div`. What you really want is one instance of that `AdminCtrl`. You can achieve this by moving the `ng-controller` directive to the outermost container element.

```
<div ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
    <div class="bar">
        <li ng-repeat="order in submitted">
            // your markup
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <li ng-repeat="order in accepted">
            // your markup
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!